# Jquery display time for specific location

Tags: jquery, date, time, location, zone

Using the code below I'm able to successfully display the local time on a site. I am using this on a site built on Zurb Foundation 3 - I would like to avoid loading additional plugins.

a) How do I make this always display the time in Sydney, rather than the time at the user's end? **Is there a way to do this using the code below and not an entirely different script?**

b)Plus, if it's an easy fix, how can I make it display which day of the week it is?

```
     function updateClock ( )
```

```
{
      var currentTime = new Date ( );
      var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
      var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
      var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );    



      // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
       currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
       currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

          // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
           var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM"; 



         // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
           currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours; 



      // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
           currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

          // Compose the string for display
           var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;


        $("#clock").html(currentTimeString); }

$(document).ready(function()
{setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this link

**http://www.techtricky.com/jquery-code-to-show-time-in-different-countries/**

And the demo is showing the day name in the result.

## HTML & JS:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://techtricky.com/wp-content/jquery/jquery.jclock.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
           $("#zones").change(function(){
           if ($('#time-cont .time').length>0){ $('#time-cont .time').remove();}
       var offset = $(this).val();    
           if (offset == '') return;       

       $('#time-cont').append('<div class="time"></div>');

           var options = {
            format:'<span class=\"dt\">%A, %d %B %I:%M:%S %P</span>',
            timeNotation: '12h',
            am_pm: true,
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, Times New Roman',
            fontSize: '20px',
            foreground: 'black',
            background: 'yellow',
            utc:true,
            utc_offset: offset
          }

          $('#time-cont .time').jclock(options);
       });
     });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
   <select id="zones">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="10">Australia</option> // Australia UTC offset value is 10
    <option value="8">China</option>
    <option value="5.5">India</option>
    <option value="12">Newzealand</option>
    <option value="0">UK</option>
    <option value="-5">US EST</option>

  </select>
  <div id="time-cont"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I eliminate the select option stage from this?

Comment: Hi Wiz Kid - thanks for the JsFiddle. Yes, I can see that this works using the UTC offset. Does this mean I would have to change the offset when daylight savings switches?